# How do I say "Don't let your dreams be dreams"?

Tags: english-to-japanese

You know, that meme https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0. I'm pretty sure there has to be a good Japanese equivalent, but for now I'm trying to come up with a version I can share with my friend.

What I have now is:

> 夢を夢に居させない

or

> 夢は夢に居させない

But I'm not sure about that. What interpretation would fit the original high-energy expression the most?

Comment: What meme? Some extra explanation of what exact nuance you want to express could be useful

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I thought everybody knew it, but I guess not. I added it as a link.

Comment: [「夢を夢でほっとけないよ　叶えなくちゃ！」](https://youtu.be/s0LrJa0izgQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say 「夢を夢で終わらせるな。」 (*lit.* Don't let your dream end up being a dream.)